# origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy with angular and spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

I am trying to do simple CRUD with angular and spring. I implemented JWT Authentication in my spring boot app. After that whenever I do Insert operations it works fine, but whenever I tried to edit and delete it give 'origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy' error. Why I am getting this error I added 'CorsFilter' bean in security config, but it still gives me same error.
Before adding JWT Athentication all CRUD oprations was working fine.

Please tell me why I am getting this error.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
            http.
            cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
        .and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()                                                                
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()                  
                .antMatchers("/").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      
                .antMatchers("/*").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), customUserDetailService));
    }
      
    @Bean   
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "xsrfheadername","xsrfcookiename"
        ,"X-Requested-With","XSRF-TOKEN","Accept", "x-xsrf-token","withcredentials","x-csrftoken"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("custom-header1", "custom-header2"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration); 
        return source; 
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```java
@RestController
public class StudentController {

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @PostMapping(value = "/info")
    public List<Info> addproduct(@RequestBody Info info) {
        signupDAO.add(info);
     
        List<Info> addinfo = signupDAO.getAllInfo();
     
        return addinfo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/infoDelete/{id}")
    public void deleteStudent(@PathVariable int id) {
        System.out.println("this is deleteid");
            signupDAO.delete(id);    
    }
     
    @PutMapping("/infos/{id}")
    public String updateStudent(@RequestBody Info info, @PathVariable int id) {

        info.setId(id);

        signupDAO.update(info); 

        return "info";
    }
}
```

**LoginService.ts**

```
webInfo(data: Student): Observable<any> {
    const url = '/info';
    return this.httpClient.post(this.serverUrl + url, data);
}

editPlan(data: Student, id: any): Observable<any> {
    const url = `/infos/${id}`;
    return this.httpClient.put(this.serverUrl + url, data);
}

deletePlan(id: any): Observable<any> {
    const url = `/infoDelete/${id}`;
    return this.httpClient.delete(this.serverUrl + url);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 6 + Spring Boot: Error: "from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56560927/angular-6-spring-boot-error-from-origin-http-localhost4200-has-been-bl)

Comment: i tried many solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: For local testing you can start chrome without cors checking, e.g. on mac with:  
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security

Comment: ok, I am not quite sure, but your cors configuration is either broken or  something is wrong. because if 1 operation is working fine gives signs of broken configuration.

Comment: should i need to add jwt token in these request?

Comment: @emotionlessbananas I posted solution on my problem. but still i dont understand why insert was working but edit and delete blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked..

I removed this line from **SecurityConfig.java** and all delete and edit worked.

```
 cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
```